# PHP: if statement testing if DB value equals a number - if true execute multiple sql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, phpmyadmin

*Hello, I am trying to make php code that executes multiple sql queries as long as a certain database value equals 1. If that value does not equal one, then redirect the page to oops.php.*

---

**Here is my code so far:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myUser";
$password = "myPass";
$dbname = "cashball_accounts";
$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];

// Create connection

$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Fetch the existing value of the cash_amount against that particular user here. You can use the SELECT cash_amount from users where userid = $userid

$_SESSION['cash_amount'] += $_POST['cashmade'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET cashincheck = 0 WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
$result = $stmt->execute();


if($result)
{
   echo "cashin complete!";
}
else
{
   echo mysqli_error($conn);
   session_start();
   session_unset();
   session_destroy();
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

*So I want everything from the //Fetch comment to the if($result) to execute if the variable "cashincheck" is equal to 1 in the database.*

**For example:**

```
if(SELECT cashincheck FROM users WHERE id = ? = 1) {

$_SESSION['cash_amount'] += $_POST['cashmade'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET cashincheck = 0 WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
$result = $stmt->execute();


    } else {
//redirect to oops.php
}
```

**/\ I know this wont work at all it's just an example /**

I also want to make several other if statements and update the database accordingly, meaning more sql queries and if statements will be needed,so how would I add more?

another example for a separate if statement:

```
 if($_POST['cashmade'] < $_POST['type']) {

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET moneymade = moneymade + $_POST['cashmade'] WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
    $result = $stmt->execute();

} else {

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET moneylost = moneylost + $_POST['type'] - $_POST['cashmade'] WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $userid);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Run your `SELECT` statement to extract the value of `cashincheck`, compare to 1.  The code in your **For example** just needs to be completed.  You already know how to run queries, just run the `SELECT`.

Comment: You're going to need to read up on [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) before you proceed. Credit/debit transactions must be handled in a consistent and *atomic* manner. You are not doing that here. If you're modifying more than one record you *must* use a transaction to properly unwind everything should an error occur. If you don't your database will slowly fall out of sync and all the numbers in it will become meaningless.

Comment: **WARNING**: **BIND ALL YOUR PARAMETERS** not just *some* of them. This code not only has huge bugs, it's full of [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @tadman could you give me an example on binding the parameters, and could you refer me to a link with example code for the transactions? I'm new to PHP. Thanks

Comment: You're literally using them in your code. That's what `bind_param` does. What you need to do is bind *all* of those parameters, not just some. In short: **DO NOT** put `$`-type variables in your queries. One tip to help avoid mistakes: Always use single quotes for your SQL: `prepare('...')` means interpolation can't happen by accident.

Comment: If this code is being created for academic reasons there's a number of things you're going to have to explore and learn. If this is for commercial purposes I'd strongly urge you to abandon this code because it's too vulnerable to deploy.

Comment: Yeah this is for commercial use... Do you mind helping me re-write this? I thought i was close to finishing.

Comment: @tadman If you put it in a separate answer and everything works fine I will mark you as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: That's just one problem of many in this code, though, which is why I'm concerned. If this is handling real money you have huge problems, this code will not work, will cost you, and will turn into a massive liability. Try and use an existing e-commerce system platform and build on top of that with extensions, carefully following their guidelines. If you like PHP, [Magento](http://magento.com) is a good foundation but there are many others.

Comment: @tadman i'm using paypal for people to deposit money into the site bank, and then once they make money then the money updates and can be put back into their account. Are you implying that people can tamper with it and steal a ton of extra money?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, that's exactly what I'm saying. If someone can exploit a race condition and you don't notice they can manufacture money out of thin air. If you pay that out by accident you're not going to get it back. This happens *all the time* when people deploy un-audited code. If there's an exploit in a platform like Magneto it's front-page news. If your site gets exploited nobody will notice but (hopefully) you. Where you're handling real money and people can get paid out, *expect* someone to take an interest in your site and try and crack it.

Comment: Too many companies, cryptocurrency exchanges in particular, have been cracked wide open because they deployed hand-rolled code that was neither properly audited, nor had unit tests to verify it works correctly under a variety of circumstances. I really hate to be alarmist here, but the risks are real and the consequences can be severe. You do not want to explain to people that the reason their account balances are gone, to the investors that the company is insolvent is all because of something preventable like a SQL injection bug.

Comment: Are there any free and easy to use "money managers" because i don't think magento is free.